# What's the naming rules for Class itself?

Tags: c#, class, types

For example;
"Console class" 
"Acme.Collections.Stack class"

One says, the precise term should be a "class". 
Of course, the term "type" can be used because it is a general term.

In my opinion, "class" is not correct.
"class" should be used only for user_defined types.
Consle, Stack are not custom ones so it should be "types".

The MSDN says like this;
A class is a construct that enables you to create your own custom types by grouping together variables of other types, methods and events.

Any good suggestions ?

Comment: What you suggest to call the framework classes? Type is more generic which can be class, interface etc.

Comment: A `class` is a specific `type`.  `Type` is the general term, `class` is a specific term.

Comment: If it says "class" in the first line of its definition, then it is a class.

Comment: Arghya C;; that's right. We have BCL/FCL etc already. I do not have any idea.

Comment: Sam Axe;; What do you mean specifically with "specific" ? It is not so clear.

Comment: What @SamAxe means is, `Type` is more generalized, while `Class` is specialized than `Type`. A `Class` is a more specific (specialized) type of `Type`.

Comment: @Jason you can tag people with `@username`. Just FYI.

Comment: @ArghyaC thanks for the nice tip

Comment: @Polyfun ;; You are right. I've learn it from You. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the whole point. The documentation says you can define custom types using the `class` keyword. It doesn't mean only you can create such types. Framework has a set of libraries written by programmers like you to create "*their*" custom types to ease your development. In short, framework types are also user defined types.

C# basically has types - some are `class`, some are `struct`, some are `interface`, some are `enum`, some are `delegate`, some are `[]` (arrays). Internally some of those types are just classes btw.

Comment: "framework types are also user defined types"--> This is a big shot to me. THANKS.

Answer (score 4):

As MSDN says, `class` is a specific reference `type` which allows you grouping together variables.

A `type` is a more general term which describes `class` and other structures like

- `struct`
- `enum`
- `delegate`
- `Generic Type`
- `interfaces`
- `Etc...`

As you can see in the `System.Type` `class` which contains data about a `type`, it supports many other `type`s other than class as mentioned above:

[image: Type]

And even though MSDN says:

> your own custom types

.NET `class`es also fall under that definition since their are *".NET's own custom types"*.

The definitions for `class` and `type` are defined very well and you should not try to define them yourself.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, fixed

Comment: +1 for *The definition for class and type are defined very well and you should not try to define them youself.*

Comment: They use the broadest meaning of "custom". It is very clear to me now. Thanks a LOT. Above are really nice explanations. I have guided wrong way (way wrong) by lots, lots of the local idiot(s) (including best selling C# books author in my area).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what are you asking here, but I think your'e confusing the terms a bit, so let me clarify it.

**TYPE**
In c# [types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) are constructs that contain logic (methods) and data (members, properties and variables). There are several distinctions between different types:

- [Built-in types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx)
- Custom types

and:

- [Reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx)
- [Value types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)

Note that for the most part the two distinctions are completely unrelated. There are built-in reference types and you can define a custom value type. The fact that a type is built in means that it's implemented inside the [.net clr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4(v=vs.110).aspx), meaning you can't see their implementation, even with a reflector (see the [MethodImpl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute). The built-in types represent the building block for all other types. Everything else in the language is in some form a combination of them.

**CLASS**
Class is a type modifier meaning this type is passed by reference. When you send a class type as a parameter to a method, the method receives it's and all changes are made to the same instance of the type (unless you change the reference). Also, class can accept `null` as their value.

**[STRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx)**
When a type is defined as a struct, it means it's treated as a value type. When you pass it as a parameter to the method, the method would get a *copy* of the instance, and all changes would apply to the copy only, and not to the original instance. Structs cannot accept null (see the [Nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable(v=vs.110).aspx) class).

So, you can use the terms `type` and `class` interchangeably for the most part. Especially when talking about classes in the .net framework. The only unique types are the Built-in types. The only real distinction you can make is between them and the rest of the types. Int and List are fundamentally different, since int is implement inside the *.net clr*, and List is implement in the *framework*, using the clr. List and a custom type you create are much more alike, and calling one a `type` and the other a `class` is completely meaningless.

Comment: Wow. Tha is amazing. The exact point what I do not have pinpointed understanding about is the term "Custom". I have thought I am the only custom(er) maker of THE class. But, I was worng, ALL are customs. Mr. Hejlsberg (I asked him this question yesterday morning, and got the same answer), MS guys and etc etc could/should be custom. Now all are clear. Thanks again.